# mysql последняя запись в БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ (не просто в таблице)

Tags: mysql

сайт почти готов, создает рубрики, записи, их редактирует и удаляет, выводит последние новости...
НО
из таблицы (то есть категории)... соответственно категории показываются в алфавитном (или каком то другом) порядке. И, если новая запись будет в категории где то внизу по списку, ее сайт выведет в последнем порядке - внизу списка....

есть ли какие-то команды, которые выводят последние записи из базы данных вообще ( тоесть при сравнении всех таблиц), а не только последние записи с одной таблицы?

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос более точно, и приведите код который выводит записи из таблиц. А то получите ответ, что "какие-то команды есть"

Comment: команда которая выбирает последние записи из таблицы "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $countlist, 5"; где $table это название таблицы........но нужно что то подобное только последние записи вообще из базы данных ( тоесть чтоб сначала бралась последняя запись из каждой таблицы, а потом сортировались дальше между собой и таким образом получались бы последние записи из базы данных)

Comment: @user198532 Запросы могут работать только с таблицами и никак иначе. так что из каждой таблицы union собирать боле менее поеследние записи, все вместе сортировать по дате и отбирать из них уже последние. Это разумеется делается одним запросом. И что то мне подсказывает, что у вас проблемы с структурой базы, раз вам это понадобилось

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться таблицами `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).

Однако, ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО, вам нужно иметь достаточный доступ к базе. Т.е. если Ваш сайт хостится на бесплатном хостинге, скорее всего такого доступа у Вас нет.
Если это так, то дальше можете не читать :)

Ну а вообще `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` дает дополнительную информацию о базе и структуре таблиц.
Например:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = '[ИМЯ_БАЗЫ_ДАННЫХ]'
```

Даст Вам много данных о таблицах. Кроме всего прочего: дата последнего обновления, следующий `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
Имея эту информацию и зная структуру своих таблиц, может быть Вы и сможете выяснить, куда что было последним добавлено...

Однако, как Вам уже написали, **если Вы вынуждены это делать, то у Вас явно что-то не то с базой**.
Также немаловажно - использование `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` где-то вне базы (php код, например) это огромный риск.

Вообщем, на вопрос я Вам ответил, идею подкинул, однако НИКТО НЕ СОВЕТУЕТ ВАМ ЭТИМ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЬСЯ из соображений безопасности :)